# Correct way to use periods for daylight saving with the help of Joda Time

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime, dst

I am getting incorrect results because of the daylight savings for that day.

I used,

```
Calendar todays = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
todays.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
todays.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
todays.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
todays.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

As mentioned in [Joda-Time doc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html),

> Consider adding 1 day at the daylight savings boundary. If you use a
>   period to do the addition then either 23 or 25 hours will be added as
>   appropriate. If you had created a duration equal to 24 hours, then you
>   would end up with the wrong result.

I didn't found any example of how to implement such a period using Joda-Time.

So, I want to get the number of hours contained in each day dynamically rather hard coding it with 24 hours as mentioned.

Comment: You haven't told us what you're trying to achieve, which makes it hard to understand what you mean by "incorrect results".

Comment: @JonSkeet- I am setting the total hours for each day and then calculating values giving the amount of work done by the user each day in a chart. This involves, at which time of the day, the user did which work, etc. Since DST may be 23 or 25 hours, the results are inaccurate.

Comment: `What I am trying to achieve?`  - I want to get the number of hours in each day dynamically rather hard coding it with 24 hours as mentioned in question.

Comment: You say "as mentioned in the question" as if it were already there when I left my comment - it wasn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet  - ok. I thought it is apparent by what I wrote in question. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to use something like:

```
public int getHoursInDay(LocalDate date, DateTimeZone zone) {
    DateTime start = date.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(zone);
    DateTime end = date.plusDays(1).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(zone);
    return new Duration(start, end).getStandardHours();
}
```

EDIT: If you're using a version of Joda Time which doesn't support `Duration.getStandardHours()` you could use:

```
public int getHoursInDay(LocalDate date, DateTimeZone zone) {
    DateTime start = date.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(zone);
    DateTime end = date.plusDays(1).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(zone);
    long millis = new Duration(start, end).getMillis();
    return (int) (millis / DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_HOUR);
}
```

Comment: It says, `The method getStandardHours() is undefined for the type Duration`. The method `getStandardSeconds()` is there which is returning `long` type and not `int`.

Comment: @VedPrakash: Which version of Joda Time are you using? See http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#getStandardHours()